# How to stretch/modify an image to a given template?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an image that contains an outline of a triangle.

I also have a piece of paper with the same triangle which a researcher allows a chimpanzee to color in. Then I take a photo of that piece of paper.

I want to process that photo and manipulate it so that the triangle in the photo is now just like the triangle in the reference image file even if the photo has to be stretched, rotated, etc.

I found opencv's template matching which seems like it might handle the first bit- the identifying the reference template in the photo. But now I need to find methods to modify the photo to fit the template.

Can anyone point me to a good place to get started?

Comment: A photo would be a good start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to find the affine transform between the two images. After you will find the transformation between them you will apply it on the photo.

In order to find the affine transform you need to find a set of 3 corresponding points between the two images. In your case a good choice will be just the 3 vertices of the triangle. In order to get the transform in opencv use getAffineTransform.

After that apply the transform on the photo image using opencv warpAffine.

A good tutorial on this you can find at
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html